# How can I use exec / kill while having std=c99?

Tags: c, c99

When I try to use exec:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    exec("echo `Hello World`");
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
code.c:11: error: implicit declaration of function ‘exec’
make: *** [code.o] Error 1
```

I have to use std=c99 and I can't add any other compiler flags. How can I use exec (or a simmilar call)?

I guess the solution will be the same for kill, wouldn't it?

Comment: Is this on Linux? According to `man exec` there's only `execl()` etc. Also, you are probably thinking about `system()` rather than `exec()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your includes, it appears like you're using a Unix of some kind. There is no `exec` call. There is `execl`, `exexlp`, and others with names depending on the exact types of parameters. Check the man page for 'exec' for details.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` or `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`, or use the equivalent `-D` options on the command line to the compiler.

Comment: Are you sure the `exec` function exists?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on my Ubuntu 11.04 -- do these feature macros require newer glibc?

Comment: Oh I missed that he was using the wrong name. Still, with `-std=c99`, you need the right feature test macros to get anything but plain C interfaces in the headers.